# Separar texto por parrafos, recibido de campo SQL - PHP

Tags: php, sql

Este es mi codigo PHP

```
$contenedor = isset( $idUrl ) ? $ClassNews->generarBanner( $idUrl ) :   $ClassNews->generarBanner();
                    foreach( $contenedor as $datosNoticia ){}

<p class="texto-body-noticia">
   <?php 
       echo $datosNoticia["description_new"];
   ?>   
 </p>
```

Logro obtener el texto de mi campo SQL pero **me llega sin separación de parrafos.**  Quisiera saber **¿Existe una posibilidad de separar mi texto?**, o tendria que haber creado un campo por cada parrafo. 
**Muchas gracias**

Comment: ya probaste concatenarle un salto de línea a través de una etiqueta `<br />`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto html no interpreta los saltos de linea por lo que debemos añadir `<br>` para generar un salto de linea. PHP provee la función [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) que nos permite insertar saltos de linea html en las nuevas lineas de un texto.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$texto = <<<EOD
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Nulla ornare et erat vel semper. Aenean eget consectetur leo. 

Pellentesque justo dolor, pulvinar vitae urna at, rutrum vulputate eros.
EOD;

echo nl2br($texto);
?>
```

Resultado

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Nulla ornare et erat vel semper. Aenean eget consectetur leo.

Pellentesque justo dolor, pulvinar vitae urna at, rutrum vulputate eros.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 0):

Si lo vas a mostrar en HTML, puedes agregar `white-space: pre-line;` al estilo CSS del elemento padre.