# Respetar espacios de un TextArea

Tags: php, html

Tengo un sistema el cual sirve para hacer cotizaciones, pero ese no es el caso, los vendedores necesitan colocar una descripción en su cotización para describir el producto que se esta vendiendo.
Coloque un `<textarea>` para que el vendedor pueda escribir su descripción del producto, posteriormente poder mandarla a un formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de dar click en "Guardar Cotización" se genera un formulario con toda la información proporcionada al sistema, en el cual por medio de `$variable = $_POST['textarea'];` recopilo la información del `<textarea>` el problema es que en el formulario muestra la descripción sin salto de linea, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que requiro es que me respete los saltos de linea que se hacen en el `<textarea>` ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionarlo? Adjunto mi codigo.

> Codigo del Textarea

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal89" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <strong><h4 class="modal-title">Descripcion</h4></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" name="extrainfo" id="extrainfo">
                <option>REQ/CONTROL</option>
                <option>SPEC</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="extrainfo2" id="extrainfo2" placeholder="Comienza a escribir...">
        </div>
        </div>
            <br/>
          <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
          <br/>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Guardar Cotizacion</button>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

> Formulario donde tomo el valor

```
<?php 
$describir = $_POST['description'];
?>
<table class=" table-bordered ">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color:#CFCFCF">
                <th class="text-center" width="350">Articulo / Servicio</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="130">Unidad</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="65">Cantidad</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="100">V. Unitario</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="130">Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $nombredelproyecto?></td>
                <td class="text-center">Pieza</td>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $cantidaddeproyec?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><span class="text-left">$</span> <?php echo $totaldelproyecto;?></td>
                <?php $eltotaldelosproyectos = $cantidaddeproyec * $totaldelproyecto;?>
                <td class="text-center"><span class="text-left">$</span> <?php echo $eltotaldelosproyectos;?><input type="hidden" name="total-fila" class="total-fila" value="<?php echo $eltotaldelosproyectos;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $describir;?></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Subtotal:</td>
        <th class="text-center">$ <?php echo $eltotaldelosproyectos?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="eliva" id="eliva" value="<?php echo $IVA?>">
<?php if($IVA == "0.08"){ $totalconiva = $eltotaldelosproyectos * 0.08;?>
        <td>IVA 8%</td>
<?}else{$totalconiva = $eltotaldelosproyectos * 0.16;?>
    <td>IVA 16%</td>
<?}?>

        <th class="text-center"><span class="text-left">$</span> <?php echo $totalconiva?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <th>TOTAL <?php echo $informacion['monedacotiz']?></th>
        <th class="text-center"><span class="text-left">$</span> <?php echo $ultimototis = $totalconiva + $eltotaldelosproyectos;?></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Si la tabla es en html podrias condicionar que cada vez que hay un salto de linea en el textarea se agregue un \n asi se va a la base de datos y al volver al html deberia quedar como un salto de linea, **no lo he intentado, solo estoy dando una hipotesis**

Comment: Utiliza la funcion `nl2br();` puedes ver un ejemplo en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258502/separar-texto-por-parrafos-recibido-de-campo-sql-php/258522#258522 De la cual esta puede der un duplicado. Un saludo

Comment: Acabo de utilizar la funcion que propusiste Xerif y me ha funcionado de maravilla, muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro de que lo solucionaras. Marco para cerrar como: Posible duplicado de [Separar texto por parrafos, recibido de campo SQL - PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258502/separar-texto-por-parrafos-recibido-de-campo-sql-php)